# SessionHandler issue

Tags: php, session

I have a problem with my SessionHandler class. It inserts an blank session at each refresh, and when you insert something in session, the print_r function doesn't show all available options. What could generate the problem?

[SessionHandler Class](http://notey.it/n/aHo)

Answer (score 1):

why not modify SessionHandler::sessionWrite() to log debug_backtrace() info to a temporary log file. Then you can see this "blank" session and where sessionWrite was called from and realize what to fix? So just something easy like:

```
    public function sessionWrite($sessionId, $sessionData)
    {
        file_put_contents('test.txt',serialize(debug_backtrace()),FILE_APPEND);
        ......
    }
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances' in F:\xampp\htdocs\library\Session.php on line 63
( ! ) PDOException: You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances in F:\xampp\htdocs\library\Session.php on line 63

Comment: ok, what if you change serialize() to var_export(), so file_put_contents('test.txt',var_export(debug_backtrace()),FILE_APPEND);

Comment: with this debug added, do you experience the issue? Are there still two records added to the db(one empty)? If so, there should be also two records in the debug file, can you prepend debug info with some text marker and put all file contents onto notey.it. When you see there two calls of sessionWrite() you can map the blank session in the db either to the first or the second call. And then from debug file stack trace you can determine where it was called from and get rid or fix that call

Comment: the strange thing is where i am now .. it doesn't create an empty session each time i refresh the page the only problem that seems to persist now ( on this test server) is that on print_r session .. i don't get any output or even when i'm trying to access a session

Comment: If you're testing under windows, you can try to setup mysql-proxy: http://lamp-dev.com/wp-content/uploads/mysql-proxy.zip , just unpack it and change your mysql server address in start.bat , then change your DSN in the app to localhost:4040. After this you should see all queries going to mysql from your app and see where the bug is, it might be in INSERT or SELECT (write or read) session

Comment: that's a very nice program i didn't know about it :-) thank you very much. i finally had some time off to setup mysql proxy and this is what i get even if i don't have any sessions setup on that page.. :-( [mysql proxy dump](http://notey.it/n/aWI)

Comment: so you see that sessionValue is empty, you may dump and see whether it comes into the method and then debug from there. But the reason is that it is not passed into the query

Answer (score 0):

are you using session_start() on document top ?

Comment: first i define some vars then i include some files for autoloading classes..  then i create an instance of the class.. and in the __construct() i call session_start before outputing anything to the browser(ob_start())